# Handlebars each has context of parent

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I've been searching the web for hours, and I don't know why this code doesn't work.

I'm trying to loop through an array, in which is another array I want to loop through. If I try to display a variable in that object, it won't show anything. However, if I try to log 'this' or the value I want to log, it shows the correct context.

```
<div class="invoice-content">
    {{#usageData}}
    <h2>{{title}}</h2>
    <table class="bill-detail-table js-table-{{id}}">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            {{#columns}}
                {{log this}}
                {{log label}}
                <th>{{label}}</th>
            {{/columns}}
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    {{/usageData}}
</div>
```

When I log 'this', I will show the correct context:
`Object {label: "Date", value: "foobar"}`
When I log 'label', it also shows the right value: 'Date'.

But for whatever reason, the `<th>{{label}}</th>`, stays empty. But I'm able to show to correct value there by displaying `<th>{{columns.[0].label}}</th>`. Besides that, I also noticed that it doesn't loop through the complete columns array. It only walks through that array once.

My input data looks as following: 
[image: Handlebars input data]

I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Your code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/tomi77/fk5y2zab/

Comment: Thanks for you reply Tomasz! I was running my template as part of the html page and not in a script tag to make it more clear for a content editor to edit the text. But for some reason it will break when it is inline in the html, and it won't if you put the html in a script tag. Probably because the browser strips out some invalid html (e.g. the {{#colums}}).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the fact that the template was inline instead of in script tags. I think the browser did some rending things, which caused the script to break. As soon as I moved everything back into a script tag, the problem was solved!